# trying to get the reward points and I can't set the value of Books

Tags: java, setvalue

Hello I am taking java class and I have this program as an assignment. I am trying to figure out who to set the value and return the calculation using Scanner class. I am a total beginner in java ( in any comp. language). if you can help me figure out the issue. I have look everywhere but I can't find the solution.

```
/**
* Write a description of class BookclubTester here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
    import java.util.Scanner;  

    public class BookclubTester {

        public BookclubTester() {
            String  studentName;
        } 
 
        public static void main (String [] args) {
 
            int books;  
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 5) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Please provided your name :" );
                String studentName = input.nextLine();
    
                Bookclub rewardsProgram = new Bookclub();
                System.out.println("Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month " );
                books = input.nextInt();
     
                rewardsProgram.setBooks(books);
   
                System.out.println(rewardsProgram.getRewardPoints());
                count++;
            }
        }
   }
```

#### This is the class

```
/**
*
* @author
*/
public class Bookclub {

    private  String studentName;
    private int books = 0;
    private  int rewardPoints;

    public Bookclub () {
 
    }

    public int getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(int books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public int getCalculateRewardPoints (){
        return rewardPoints;
    }

    public int getRewardPoints() {
        return rewardPoints;
    }

    public void setCalculateRewardPoints (int rewardPoints) {
        this.rewardPoints = rewardPoints;
        if (books == 0) {
            rewardPoints = 0;
            System.out.println("Your points are:" + rewardPoints);
       } else if (books == 1) {
            rewardPoints = 5;
       }else if (books == 2) {
            rewardPoints = 15;//
       }else if(books == 3) {
            rewardPoints = 30;
       }else if(books == 4) {
            rewardPoints = 60;
       } 
    }

    public void setRewardPoints(int rewardPoints) {
        this.rewardPoints = rewardPoints;
            if(rewardPoints == 0) {
                rewardPoints = 0;
            }else if(rewardPoints ==5) {
                System.out.println("Your points are : " + rewardPoints);
            }else if(rewardPoints == 15) {
                System.out.println("Your points are:" + rewardPoints);
            }else if(rewardPoints == 30) { 
                System.out.println("Your points are:" + rewardPoints);
            }else if(rewardPoints == 60) { 
                System.out.println("Your points are:" + rewardPoints);
            }  
        }
}
```

Comment: `getCalculateRewardPoints` and `getRewardPoints` have the same method body. That's weird, don't you think?

Comment: yes I got the answer. .. I did it a little different than what it was suggested, but I was point to the right direction... you guys are amazing.

Comment: MC ... I notice that after you mention it ... I got rid of most of my code and it is working now ... thanks for looking over my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should address the following problems present in your code:

1. The declaration `String  studentName;` inside the constructor, `BookclubTester(){}` is useless.
2. You have neither defined the setter and getter methods for `studentName` nor set it into the object, `rewardsProgram`.
3. Instantiate `Scanner` outside the `while` loop i.e.  `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` should be outside the while loop. You can reuse the same `Scanner` object instantiated outside the `while` loop.
4. I also suggest you use `Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine())` instead of `input.nextInt()` to avoid problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo).
5. You have not set `rewardPoints` into the object, `rewardsProgram`. Ideally, the method calculating/setting the reward points should be called from `setBooks` because the reward points are based on the number of books.
6. There should be a condition (e.g. `if (books >= 4)`) for the reward points when the number of books is more than `4`.

Given below is the code incorporating these recommendations:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Bookclub {

    private String studentName;
    private int books = 0;
    private int rewardPoints;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public int getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(int books) {
        this.books = books;
        setRewardPoints(books);
    }

    public int getCalculateRewardPoints() {
        return rewardPoints;
    }

    public int getRewardPoints() {
        return rewardPoints;
    }

    public void setRewardPoints(int books) {
        if (books == 0) {
            rewardPoints = 0;
        } else if (books == 1) {
            rewardPoints = 5;
        } else if (books == 2) {
            rewardPoints = 15;//
        } else if (books == 3) {
            rewardPoints = 30;
        } else if (books >= 4) {
            rewardPoints = 60;
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int books;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (count < 5) {
            Bookclub rewardsProgram = new Bookclub();

            System.out.print("Please provided your name: ");
            String studentName = input.nextLine();
            rewardsProgram.setStudentName(studentName);

            System.out.print("Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month: ");
            books = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            rewardsProgram.setBooks(books);

            System.out.println("Reward points: " + rewardsProgram.getRewardPoints());
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please provided your name: Test1
Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month: 2
Reward points: 15
Please provided your name: Test2
Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month: 1
Reward points: 5
Please provided your name: Test3
Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month: 7
Reward points: 60
Please provided your name: Test4
Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month: 0
Reward points: 0
Please provided your name: Test5
Please provide the numbers of books purchase for the  month: 4
Reward points: 60
```

You can still think of many validations (e.g. check if the number of books is not negative) and I hope, these suggestions will help you design your program for those things.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bit of confusion in your code, but for beginners it's normal :)

First of all, in your main class you are printing `rewardsProgram.getRewardPoints()` that just simply returns `rewardPoints` which is null!

When you set your books inside `setBooks` method you have to call a second method to calculate your rewardsPoints, in your case it's the `setRewardsPoints`. Inside this method you have to use your variable `books` to get your points, you can use something like:

```
switch(books){
  case 0:
   rewardsPoints=0; break;
  case 1:
   rewardsPoints=5; break;
  ...
}
```

This is how you should calculate your points. To print rewardsPoints, simply do:

```
System.out.println(rewardsProgram.getRewardPoints());
```

You also need to clear a little bit your class, some methods are useless! This is a simple way to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and looking over my code. It Help a Ton.....

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BookClubMember {

    private final String name;
    private int books;
    private int rewardPoints;

    public BookClubMember(String name, int numberOfBooks) {
            this.name = name;
            setBooks(numberOfBooks);
    }

    public BookClubMember(String name) {
            this(name, 0);

    }

    public final String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public final int getBooks() {
            return books;
    }

    public final void setBooks(int numberOfBooks) {
            int oldValue = books;
            if (numberOfBooks <= 0) {
                books = 0;
            } else {
                books = numberOfBooks;
            }
            if (oldValue != books) {
                // update your points if they have changed.
                rewardPoints = calculateRewardPoints(books);
            }
    }

        
    public final int getRewardPoints() {
            return rewardPoints;
    }

        /**
         * This can be overridden in the future if you ever wanted to extend
         * this class and make a "Platinum Member"... etc where they get more points
         * per book, or they are on a linear scale, etc etc.
         * 
         *
         * @param bookCount
         * @return
         */
        protected int calculateRewardPoints(int bookCount) {
            switch (bookCount) {
                case 0:
                    return 0;
                case 1:
                    return 5;
                case 2:
                    return 15;
                case 3:
                    return 30;
                default:
                    return 60;
            }
        }
    }
```

And your main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            // so you need to work in a scanner object here to collect a name, and number of books.
            // once you have both you can create a new BookClubMember object.
            // I'm cheating and manually putting them in :)
            BookClubMember member = new BookClubMember("Johnny", 5);
            System.out.println(member.getName() + " has " + member.getRewardPoints() + " points " + " for " + member.getBooks() + " books");
        }
```

Output:

> Johnny has 60 points  for 5 books